# News Feed via graph API very different from what I see at facebook.com

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

I'm experimenting with the Graph API, specifically the News Feed query (me/home). And right off the bat, I can see that the JSON returned does not match what I see on my own facebook page. The API returns some objects that are not on the page, and vice versa. I can't figure out what's going on here. I don't think it's about people I've unsubscribed from or anything like that.

Is this expected behavior, or am I doing something wrong? Is there documentation somewhere that explains what the difference is?

*edit 22-Nov-11*: this is never going to be answered, is it.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. Did you manage to discover what was the problem? thanks!

Comment: The Facebook news feed has a setting: show top stories or most recent stories. What setting have you selected? There's a little triangle next to the *News Feed* link in the left-hand side-bar.

Answer (score -1):

NewsFeed via api ordered by time but on facebook.com ordered by top stories 
Open your recent news feed > https://www.facebook.com/?sk=h_chr
you will find that it's the same as api (y)